# .sh file is not running changing directory command

Tags: command-line, sudo, .sh

my contents of .sh file are

```
sudo -i
cd /home/madhu131313/Documents/
```

I run it ,then it asked for root password, it changed to root, but it doesn't execute the changing directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing directory affects the current process. It **does not** affect the parent process; that would be a huge security hole. Please see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/060